# How to quickly create multiple summary tables with group_by() / summarise()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with N vars, M categorical and 2 numeric. I would like to create M data frames, one for each categorical variable.

Eg.,

```
data %>%
group_by(var1) %>%
summarise(sumVar5 = sum(var5),
meanVar6 = mean(var6))

data %>%
group_by(varM) %>%
summarise(sumVar5 = sum(var5),
meanVar6 = mean(var6))
```

etc...

Is there a way to iterate through the categorical variables and generate each of the summary tables? That is, without needing to repeat the above chunks M times.

Alternatively, these summary tables don't have to be individual objects, as long as I can easily reference / pull the summaries for each of the M variables.

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (I hope). Creates a list of data frames with the formula you have:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create sample data frame
data <- data.frame(var1 = sample(1:2, 5, replace = T),
                   var2 = sample(1:2, 5, replace = T),
                   var3 = sample(1:2, 5, replace = T),
                   varM = sample(1:2, 5, replace = T),
                   var5 = rnorm(5, 3, 6),
                   var6 = rnorm(5, 3, 6))

# Vars to be grouped (var1 until varM in this example)
vars_to_be_used <- names(select(data, var1:varM))

# Function to be used
group_fun <- function(x, .df = data) {
  .df %>%
      group_by_(.x) %>%
      summarise(sumVar5  = sum(var5),
                meanVar6 = mean(var6))
  }

# Loop over vars
results <- map(vars_to_be_used, group_fun)

# Nice list names
names(results) <- vars_to_be_used

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't supply a sample data.set so I created a small example to show how it works.

```
data <- data_frame(var1 = rep(letters[1:5], 2),
                   var2 = rep(LETTERS[11:15], 2),
                   var3 = 1:10,
                   var4 = 11:20)
```

A combination of tidyverse packages can get you where you need to be. 
Steps used: First we gather all the columns we want to group by on in a cols column and keep the numeric vars separate. Next we split the data.frame in a list of data.frames so that every column we want to group by on has it's own table with the 2 numeric vars. Now that everything is in a list, we need to use the `map` functionality from the purrr package. Using map, we spread the data.frame again so the column names are as we expect them to be. Finally using map we use `group_by_if` to group by on the character column and summarise the rest. All the outcomes are stored in a list where you can access what you need.

Run the code in pieces to see what every step does.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

outcomes <- data %>% 
  gather(cols, value, -c(var3, var4)) %>% 
  split(.$cols) %>%
  map(~ spread(.x, cols, value)) %>% 
  map(~ group_by_if(.x, is.character) %>% 
        summarise(sumvar3 = sum(var3),
                  meanvar4 = mean(var4)))

outcomes

$`var1`
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  var1  sumvar3 meanvar4
  <chr>   <int>    <dbl>
1 a           7     13.5
2 b           9     14.5
3 c          11     15.5
4 d          13     16.5
5 e          15     17.5

$var2
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  var2  sumvar3 meanvar4
  <chr>   <int>    <dbl>
1 K           7     13.5
2 L           9     14.5
3 M          11     15.5
4 N          13     16.5
5 O          15     17.5
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but I'm getting this error with L4: `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows.` Maybe I'm not replacing something correctly—should the `.x` be another value?

Comment: @Khashir, in that case you need to supply a dput (of a part) of your data in your question. This error appears when spreading the data has duplicate combinations of values in the vars.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll have to look at the data more carefully to see why this error comes up—off the top of my head, I don't see why there would be duplicates. I'm guessing these emerge in the intermediate steps? Anyway, I liked this answer more because it doesn't require writing a function (and is cleaner/more concise), but the other one worked regardless of duplicates. I'm guessing there's no easy way to bypass that limitation in spread?